# MySQL IF statement returning false instead of true

Tags: mysql

I tried asking about this with no answer, but it might have been my fault, maybe I didn't ask the right question, so I've decided to try again.

I created a function which should return me the ID of the spell whose damage is the highest. I wrote it like this:

`DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION`getSpellMaxDmgID`(`pCharID` int(11))
RETURNS int(11)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

```
DECLARE pdmgpts int(11) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE pdmgprstp int(11) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE pdmgmaxspellid int(11) DEFAULT 0;

IF (SELECT MAX(`damage_points`) FROM `spell` WHERE `spell`.`spell_id` IN( SELECT `spell_id` FROM `character_spell` WHERE `character_spell`.`character_id`=`pCharID`))!=NULL THEN
SET pdmgpts=(SELECT MAX(`damage_points`) FROM `spell` WHERE `spell`.`spell_id` IN( SELECT `spell_id` FROM `character_spell` WHERE `character_spell`.`character_id`=`pCharID`));
END IF;
IF (SELECT MAX(`damage_per_step`) FROM `spell` WHERE `spell`.`spell_id` IN( SELECT `spell_id` FROM `character_spell` WHERE `character_spell`.`character_id`=`pCharID`))!=NULL THEN
SET pdmgprstp=(SELECT MAX(`damage_per_step`) FROM `spell` WHERE `spell`.`spell_id` IN( SELECT `spell_id` FROM `character_spell` WHERE `character_spell`.`character_id`=`pCharID`));
END IF;
IF pdmgpts>=pdmgprstp THEN
IF (SELECT `spell_id` FROM `spell` WHERE `spell`.`damage_points`=pdmgpts AND `spell`.`spell_id` IN ( SELECT `spell_id` FROM `character_spell` WHERE `character_spell`.`character_id`=`pCharID`) LIMIT 1)!=NULL THEN
SET pdmgmaxspellid=(SELECT `spell_id` FROM `spell` WHERE `spell`.`damage_points`=pdmgpts AND `spell`.`spell_id` IN ( SELECT `spell_id` FROM `character_spell` WHERE `character_spell`.`character_id`=`pCharID`));
END IF;
ELSE
IF (SELECT `spell_id` FROM `spell` WHERE `spell`.`damage_per_step`=pdmgprstp AND `spell`.`spell_id` IN ( SELECT `spell_id` FROM `character_spell` WHERE `character_spell`.`character_id`=`pCharID`) LIMIT 1)!=NULL THEN
SET pdmgmaxspellid=(SELECT `spell_id` FROM `spell` WHERE `spell`.`damage_per_step`=pdmgprstp AND `spell`.`spell_id` IN ( SELECT `spell_id` FROM `character_spell` WHERE `character_spell`.`character_id`=`pCharID`));
END IF;
END IF;

RETURN pdmgmaxspellid;
```

END; //
DELIMITER ;`

Okay, so when I test all those if statements individualy, they all give me a value if I am using a character who has spells (is of magelike class), otherwise, they return null. Now, I am testing the function with a mage like character and yes, the individualy tested if queries give me a non null value, but when I try to call the function, it just gives me the default value I set for `pdmgmaxspellid`. For some reason, even if my statements return me a value, if just sees them as false and doesn't do what I want it to do. Does anyone see the problem here?

Here I have the statements which work with results:

`SELECT MAX(`damage_points`) FROM`spell`WHERE`spell`.`spell_id`IN( SELECT`spell_id`FROM`character_spell`WHERE`character_spell`.`character_id`=8);`
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5j76I.png)

`SELECT MAX(`damage_per_step`) FROM`spell`WHERE`spell`.`spell_id`IN( SELECT`spell_id`FROM`character_spell`WHERE`character_spell`.`character_id`=8)`
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1nX2.png)

`SELECT`spell_id`FROM`spell`WHERE`spell`.`damage_points`=30 AND`spell`.`spell_id`IN ( SELECT`spell_id`FROM`character_spell`WHERE`character_spell`.`character_id`=8) LIMIT 1`
Sadly, I can't post more than two links, but you can take my word when I say that the result is 43.

`SELECT`spell_id`FROM`spell`WHERE`spell`.`damage_per_step`=10 AND`spell`.`spell_id`IN ( SELECT`spell_id`FROM`character_spell`WHERE`character_spell`.`character_id`=8) LIMIT 1`
Same as from above, the result is 13.

Comment: Typically, `NULL` checks are handled with `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`; `anything = NULL` or `anything != NULL` results in `NULL` which is usually treated as "not true"...even when "anything" **is** null.

Comment: Did you try with `IS NOT NULL` instead of !=NULL? The IF @something = NULL THEN does not work as you expected because you can't check NULL with equality (=). NULL is a special value that is not equal to anything, not even to itself.   `SELECT IF(null IS null,1,0);` will return 1 but `SELECT IF(null = null,1,0);` will return 0.

Comment: @Daelendil, Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Keep in mind stored procedures are always far more work than using a scripting language of any sort. There's rarely a reason these days to do this work entirely in the database.

Comment: Thank you guys, IS NOT NULL works!

Comment: Thanks, tadman, I will keep it in mind in the future. This project is already at its 2600+ lines of code, so I am not able to start again due to my deadline.